# Как определить событие выхода из сна?

Tags: android, android-intent

Сразу объясню, это китайское головное устройство для авто на Android 4.4.4 Событие android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED отрабатывает идеально, а вот например на Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON не реагирует никак. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли ещё какие нибудь способы определения события выхода из сна, кроме как тщательный анализ заводского кода устройства.

Comment: лучше опишите, что  вы хотите сделать. Возможнло есть более простой способ.